# Type-class/implicit discoverability in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

In Scala, is there a way to "discover" all the type classes in scope; or more generally, all the implicits in scope? In `ghci`, `:info Monad` shows all the available `Monad`s, and `:info Maybe` shows all the available type classes for `Maybe`, I wonder if something similar exists in the Scala.

Comment: IntelliJ [can do](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Implicit+Conversions) that, but they wrote their own typechecker; I don't think something like `:info` exists in the standard Scala REPL. It's probably difficult since implicits are "more" than type classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, Scala does not have something like that. There are a few compiler options as "-Xlog-implicits" that print a bit more information, if implicits are not applicable. But there is nothing to list all implicits available in a certain context.

One could try to do this via macros, but even the macro api does not provide a direct way to do that. There is access to the typer via the compiler API and implicit search. But this API is very complicated.